# VSCode default Integrated Terminal is not changing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for some time now and until today the Terminal was working as expected.
But now I can't change the default Integrated Terminal. It's allways "cmd" no matter what I set up in the settings.

The settings.json seems to be fine:

```
{
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
"files.associations": {
    "*.testset": "feature"
},
"git.autofetch": true,
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

But every new terminal is still "cmd".
Not "bash" or "PS".

Comment: It works on my laptop... even with a space in the path. VSCode asked me if I really want to run bash.exe and each time I click on the +, a new bash window is created.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my workspace settings.
"project.code-workspace"

```
{
    ....
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"
    }
}
```

By removing this line from the file, the problem was fixed. Now I can change the default Integrated Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

**most of the time this issue happens when new updates come,
the easiest ways to solve this is:**

1. https://youtu.be/jpwfr6m50sI - here you will see how to change the default terminal
2. uninstall your vscode install the previous one (if you don't know how to do this, follow this: [How to downgrade vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346733/how-to-downgrade-vscode) )

> Dont hesitate to report to GitHub of vscode team as well as follow
> their documentaries

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.