# VSCode Python version defaults to 2.7 in the integrated terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I have VScode installed on iMac with Catalina. On the vscode the interpreter defaults to python 2.7. It remains same even after I change python interpreter and python path. I have referred to following questions with out any success.

[Question 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713465/vscode-python-version-defaults-to-2-7-in-the-integrated-terminal-no-matter-what)

[Question 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456815/vscode-default-integrated-terminal-is-not-changing)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Did the following things.

1. Changed the PATH to point to right version.
2. Changed the python interpreter in the vscode.

I did the same last night and it didn't work even after restarting vscode. Worked ok after restarting the computer.