# VSCode open by itself new editor with settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what happen, but I was working on VSCODE in windows adding neovim path to the settings.json.

I clicked inside the settings.json and vscode started to open new editor tabs by itself with the same content of settings.json.

I have uninstalled vscode several times, removed the Appdata roaming vscode, the Appdata local code, etc.  I installed the vscode again and same behavior.  I restarted my windows machine and same behavior.

The sync is on so the settings replicates to all my vscode installations.  I started my Linux machine to see if this was something that replicated to my linux version.  No, it is working normal.

I can work on VScode if I don't open the settings.  It has open new editors (clones of settings) upto 500 hundred times.

I was able to stop it when I changed directory and it asked me if I wanted to close and all open tabs.  The moment that I go to settings starts again.

Answer (score 0):

You could start to not sync extentions. Maybe one is breaking it.
But You could also try to install an older version of vs code.
[How to downgrade vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346733/how-to-downgrade-vscode)

Comment: I tried to report it as a bug.  I followed the steps from vscode: