# VSCode theme broke after last update

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I opened VSC and saw some text colors changed. There was information about the new version (v1.65), but I don't know if clicking anything is the cause of the problem. I am working in Lua and e.g. the name of the variable has changed its color (from white to light blue), the type of the variable (`local`) has changed from pink (same as the `function` in the photo) to dark blue and there's a lot more of changes. I've always used the `Dark+ (default dark)` theme. Tried to fix this in extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_plus.json but without any changes. I hope there is someone who knows how to restore the old theme.
That's before it happened:

[image: Photo from vsc on another comupter]

And that's after:

[image: Photo from my vsc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also work with FiveM Lua, and my dark theme, Atom One, also broke with v1.65.
I ended up downgrading vscode to v1.64 by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347158/18388117) StackOverflow answer.