# VSCode Sync with GitHub account (Mac) - Error while turning on Settings Sync. No account available

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode's Microsoft account sync on my Mac. I decided to change sync setting from Microsoft to GitHub account, so I:

1. Turn sync off
2. Sign out from Microsoft account
3. Restart the VSCode
4. Turn sync on and choose GitHub account
5. Try logging into GitHub in browser

but VSCode shows an error saying:

> Error while turning on Settings Sync. No account available.

Syncing is fine with Microsoft account but nothing happens with GitHub.

- OS: Sonoma 14.1
- CPU: M1
- VSCode: 1.84.0 (Latest Update)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these two links:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195532
2. [How to downgrade vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346733/how-to-downgrade-vscode)

You can download vscode from here https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82 and open it (at leat on Mac you don't need to uninstall), sync it, close and open the vscode with the newer version.

I did it myself and worked.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me from multiple accounts!