# VSCODE installed a update on my mac that VSCode DOES not support and toasted the whole thing

Tags: installation

Today VS-CODE did an update
nothing seemed to happen for a while so I restarted the app
got a message saying MY system 10.14.6 was not supported
fine
no way to roll back

shouldn't it check before it install to see if it was supported
words cannot express my disappointment...
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Builds up to November 2023 support 10.14.6, so you should be able to download one of those from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85 and replace the updated application with that. Auto-updating can be disabled by changing "Update: Mode" to "none" in the settings, as described in [How to downgrade vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347158/23400965).

Answer (score -1):

Agreed!
but don't you think if would be better the the install checked the system requirements were meet before attempting a install?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).